# Mobile Apps latest technologies research

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I am currently on a research understanding the whole buzz around some technologies that claim that they deploy themselves as cross-platform apps once you write your code in HTML5/CSS3/AngularJS/Whatever client side techonology.
I understand those technologies provide you with a bridge to the native-side of the OS you are running on, but I still lack some real important information regarding them.

1. Do all those PhoneGap/Ionic/Cordova just wrap your client-side code into an application? Is it the same as using the web-browser to get to a URL but with only some native-like additions(Camera/File etc..).
2. Do those technologies just connect to your website that is online using DNS? Or is the "Website" you are building does not sit on a server but only on the local OS? Can they run that application offline?
3. **Besides the native additions you get with those kind of technologies, why bother developing with them when you can on the other hand develop a responsive website that can also work on desktop?**
4. Can you connect to a server-side using Ionic/Phonegap? Let's say I have an MS-SQL Table I want to communicate with- is that possible?

I really have a hard time understanding what all those technologies are any good. Still, it is growing in popularity. Thanks for any light on that matter.

Answer (score 0):

> Do all those PhoneGap/Ionic/Cordova just wrap your client-side code
>   into an application? Is it the same as using the web-browser to get to
>   a URL but with only some native-like additions(Camera/File etc..).

They wrap your html, css and javascript code and provide a javascript API to use native features

> Do those technologies just connect to your website that is online
>   using DNS? Or is the "Website" you are building does not sit on a
>   server but only on the local OS? Can they run that application
>   offline?
>   You should have all the html, css and javascript inside of your app, if you do it this way the app will work offline. 
>   You can have it online too, but it won't work offline and have some problems.
>
> Besides the native additions you get with those kind of technologies,
>   why bother developing with them when you can on the other hand develop
>   a responsive website that can also work on desktop?

If you don't need any of the native features phonegap provides, then do a responsive website, the idea of phonegap is fill the gap between the browser and the native apps, some day the browser will have access to all the native features and phonegap will die.
BTW, now phonegap have a desktop platform, so you can make it work as native app for phone and still work in the browser

> Can you connect to a server-side using Ionic/Phonegap? Let's say I
>   have an MS-SQL Table I want to communicate with- is that possible?

Sure, you can make XHR calls to the server to get a XML, JSON, etc with the onlyne SQL database, you can do a POST too, and upload files.